# How to see actual React error in browser log in ASP.NET MVC application when using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, reactjs, reactjs.net

I just installed `ReactJS.NET` in my application, and plan to use it on a single page. I am used to making applications where the "whole thing" is React (and Typescript and Webpack).

However, if I simply install ReactJS.NET and import the tutorial code it works:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

But, say that we now make an error and make another **div** inside the render function, so we should get an error we cannot have adjacent elements. Then I only get the following error:

[image]

And in the console.log, I get the following error which is not going to help me:

```
Invoices:841 GET http://localhost:55075/Scripts/React/InvoiceBuilder/App.jsx net::ERR_ABORTED
```

While if I used the standard Visual Studio template for React, the actual error would show very clearly.

Is this because I am not using Typescript?
Or is there another way to get the nice error handling inside Visual Studio and the Chrome browser when dealing with React?

Comment: I think visual studio only focus on backend or desktop. Even reshapher cannot handle like this. I suggest use vscode for editing jsx like this

Comment: @hendrathings That is just not the case. If you start a Visual Studio application with React as the default template, you get the full debugging and proper error messages :-) So this template enables this somehow

Comment: ah, yeah. I see. I have created from netcore `dotnet new react`, the intellij work perfectly. it is special case for tsx, I think

Comment: I am leaving the bounty open for some more days, in the hope to get a more detailed answer. You're very welcome to mark it as an answer @hendrathings and if nothing better comes by I will award it to you before the bounty ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment,

> visual studio only focus on backend or desktop. Even reshapher cannot
>   handle like this. I suggest use `vscode` for editing jsx like this

If you still want use visual studio instead of vscode, you can check lint js/jsx using flow, here [documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/). It is use cmd/powershell/terminal to check validate code.

First install flow globaly, [link](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/)

```
npm install -g flow
```

then on root of your project, run init flow by cmd/powershell:

```
flow init
```

last, put on the top your js (ex: tutorial.jsx):

```
// @flow
class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    state = { data: this.props.initialData };
...
```

Now, you can run on cmd/powershell to check your code by

```
flow status
```

then looks like this:

[image: flow message on terminal]

The bad news, not yet plugin extension `flow` for visual studio, only [vscode](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode) for now.